# Убрать keyboard после клика telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram

Бот создает клавиатуру в ответе:

```
$keyboard = [
    "keyboard" => [[
        [
            "text" => "contact"
        ],
        [
            "text" => "location" 
        ]
    ]],
    "one_time_keyboard" => true //параметр должен убирать клавиатуру
                                //после клика на одну из кнопок
];
```

но после нажатия на одну из кнопок, символ клавиатуры остается возле поля ввода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как ее все-таки убрать?
Пока пользуюсь способом отправки нового сообщения с

```
$keyboard = [
    'remove_keyboard' => true
];
```

но это не удобно для пользователя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Истинное значение поля **one_time_keyboard** объекта [ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup) всего лишь инструктирует программу-клиент скрыть клавиатуру, но она всё равно будет доступна по нажатию на специальную кнопку.

Если в ответ на нажатие кнопки бот отправляет пользователю сообщение, можно убрать клавиатуру. Для этого в при вызове [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) нужно дополнительно в параметре **reply_markup** передать объект [ReplyKeyboardRemove](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardremove).

А метод [editMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) предназначен для редактирования полупрозрачных inline-клавиатур, которые прикрепляются к сообщению. Этот тип клавиатур был введён в [апреле прошлого года](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#april-9-2016).